# How to get Height of StackLayout after adding dynamically a view?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a StackLayout (vertical options is Start). I need to add a view to it and after that to get height of StackLayout. How can I do that?
Now after adding a view into StackLayout in code behind I get Height property equals 0.

Comment: Post some relevant sample code. It's likely you can compose your layout such that you wouldn't need to know the exact coordinates, such as stack-inside-stack or stack in the first row of a grid with "Auto" size and the second row holds whatever you want to place under the stack

Comment: When you add an item into a StackLayout, you are adding a logical item. This means that the visible item will not appear and your stacklayout will not change it's size unless the layout cycle has run through (which will happen automatically) and your new item is visible on the screen. 

However, directly after you added the new item, the reinitialization of the layout cycle will not have begun yet and therefore your stacklayout still has a height of 0.

As stated below, you can call Measure to get your new item's or the stacklayout's new dimensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In what part of code you are trying to get the size? It will not work if you check it in constructor or right after you add the view. What you can do in constructor is:

```
        layout.SizeChanged += Layout_SizeChanged;
```

and then you will get correct size

```
private void Layout_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var h = layout.Height;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a view into stacklayout like this

```
StackLayout currentColumn = columns.ElementAt(currentColumnIndex);

currentColumn.Children.Add(orderCard);
```

And wanted to get `currentColumn.Height`, but it was 0.

Instead I used `Measure`and that gave a correct `Height`

```
SizeRequest columnSizeRequest = currentColumn.Measure(OrdersContainer.Width / 5, OrdersContainer.Height);
```

Comment: Measure() isn't working either for me.  The vertical stack layout within the scrollview measures 718.1818181818181 for the min height, then I add some stuff to the layout and it still shows 718.1818181818181.  I'm literally out of options other than to guess / use trial and error on how many pixels I need add for each item I add to the layout.  Then add a hard-coded fixed amount.